# R array manipulation

Tags: arrays, r, slice, sub-array

In python lists can be sliced like this `x[4:-1]` to get from the fourth to the last element.

In R something similar can be accomplished for vectors with `x[4:length(x)]` and for multidimensional arrays with something like `x[,,,,4:dim(x)[5],,,]`.  Is this more elegant syntax for array slicing for a particular dimension from an element in the middle to the last element?

Thanks

Comment: Actually in python, x[4:-1] will skip the last element. To include the last element you just need x[4:], which is equivalent to algoriffic's (1:10)[-(1:4)] in R.

Comment: Also one off at the front! In python x[4:-1] will get the fifth (not the fourth) to the penultimate element.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the drop elements syntax:

```
> (1:10)[-(1:4)]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you are interested in slicing the last n elements of the array then you could use:

```
x[seq(length=n, from=length(x), by=-1)]
```